# Errno 14 PYCURL ERROR 7- "couldn't connect to host"

Tags: yum, repository

When trying to connnect to a remote RHEL 6 linux server which contains a list of necessary rpms for my other linux clients, I get the error above (title).

I have this `/etc/yum.repos.d/itcm_repo.repo` file on the remote host :

```
[ITCM_REPO]
name=itcm_repo Repo
baseurl=http://172.19.0.110//root/.itc-deployment/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

and httpd is installed on the server.

Can someone help me get this to work?

Comment: Outside of yum can you use a tool like `wget` or `curl` or even `nc` to connect to that URL?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and managed to fix it.
The general cause of inability to connect to an yum repository server is that an operator of such a server shuts it down for any reason (lack of money, etc). In CentOS 6 the configuration files with paths to yum repositories are located in the /etc/yum.repos.d/ folder. The names of these files are CentOS-Base.repo, CentOS-Base.repo.custom, etc. First you have to analyse error generated by yum. Yum usually tells you which server it cannot connect to. You have to write down the path to this server and try to find a file (in the /etc/yum.repos.d/ folder), which corresponds to the domain of this server. Then you have to disable that server by opening that file and changing enabled=1 to enabled=0. In my case I had the atrpms.repo file which tried to download repos from http://dl.atrpms.net/el$releasever-$basearch/atrpms/stable source server which was shut down. I disabled that source and now there is no error and I can update repos by yum. Your case my be different so you have to experiment with various combinations of enabled and disabled sources of repos.